# Why to reinvent the wheel with DSL for duration-like constructs in every library?

Tags: scala, scalatest

More rhetorical question but still need to ask it.
Today I've heard about `org.scalatest.concurrent.Eventually` trait and decided to try it (formerly I used fluent waits).
So trait is quite ok, allows to write things like:

```
def waitUntilTeamFormIsShown(implicit driver: WebDriver) = {
  eventually(Timeout(10 seconds), Interval(50 milliseconds)){
    find(xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'user_groups')]/form")) shouldBe defined
  }
  completed
}
```

But one moment I did not like: `10 seconds` and `50 milliseconds` here are not instances of the `scala.concurrent.duration.Duration` but instead you need to import:

```
import org.scalatest.time.SpanSugar._
import org.scalatest.concurrent.PatienceConfiguration._
```

So ScalaTest implements its own version of stuff which is already available in Scala library.

For example, when I work with `Future`-s and need to wait for result I will write smth like

```
Await.result(DB.matchingPointIDsByRadarID(arId)(db), 4 seconds).head
```

`4 seconds` here looks completely the same, but this time it is `scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration` and I need to use different imports:

`import scala.concurrent.duration._`

My QUESTION is: is this a good library design? I would think that probably 3rd party libraries designers tried to stick to means already available in Scala. But probably there are some elaborate reasons to implement `Span` analog of the `Duration`.

NOTE: I do think Bill Venner's ScalaTest is a great library :)